# Get attributes associated with a selected item in a drop down list AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, drop-down-menu

I'm building an app using ASP.NET Web API with AngularJS and I'm new to these frameworks. I have a drop down list which display data from the API. When I select an element from the drop down, I want to get the other attributes associated with it.

Here's the API

```
 [Route("CustomerRecords")]
    public List<Customer> Get()
    {
        return new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer { CID=1, Name="Bruce Wayne", PIN="1234", Bal=1000000, cardStatus= 0 }
            ,new Customer { CID=2, Name="Tony Stark", PIN="2246", Bal=900000, cardStatus= 0 }
            ,new Customer { CID=3, Name="Jon Snow", PIN="2398", Bal=3000, cardStatus= 1 }
            ,new Customer { CID=4, Name="Rustin Cohle", PIN="7549", Bal=450000, cardStatus= 2 }
        };
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public int CID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PIN { get; set; }
    public int Bal { get; set; }
    public int cardStatus { get; set; }
}
```

here's the module, the service and the factory method

```
var customerAppModule = angular.module("customerApp", []);

customerAppModule.controller('CustomerCtrl', function ($scope, CustomerService)
{

    getCustomerRecords();

    function getCustomerRecords() {
        CustomerService.getCustomers()

            .success(function (data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                $scope.customers = data;
            })

            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.error('failure loading the customer record', status, data);
                $scope.customers = {};
            });
    }
});

customerAppModule.factory('CustomerService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var customerService = {};
    var urlBase = 'http://localhost:51701/Customer';

    customerService.getCustomers = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase + '/CustomerRecords');
    };

    return customerService;
}]);
```

and here is my drop down

```
<select ng-change="getCustomers(details)" ng-model="details">
            <option ng-repeat="customer in customers" value="{{customer.CID}}">{{customer.Name}}</option>
        </select>
```

So, only the names appear in my drop down, but if I select a particular name, I want to be able to get its other attributes

Answer (score 0):

Your function **`getCustomers`** inside the controller should have all the details as a parameter, since you are passing it,

```
$scope.getCustomers = function(details){
   //this has all the details associated with id (details);
}
```

Comment: I need to retrieve `cardStatus` of a selected name to use in a ng-switch. I still don't understand how to get the attributes of a selected item. Forgive me if the answer seems obvious; I've just started using these frameworks less than a week ago.

Comment: you can access like details.cardStatus

Comment: @jo12345678 did the answer help?

Comment: i changed my drop down to this: `<select ng-model="details" ng-options="x.Name for x in customers"></select>` and managed to get the other attributes with `details.cardStatus`, etc...

Comment: coool, did the answer help

Answer (score 0):

use select.js library and try like following

```
 <ui-select ng-model="model" append-to-body="true">
                                <ui-select-match>
                                    <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
                                </ui-select-match>
                                <ui-select-choices repeat="item in modelList"  >
                                    <div ng-bind="item.name"  ng-click="selectValue(item)"></div>
                                </ui-select-choices>
                            </ui-select>
```